# Is there a way to group 2 div elements together so that the placement of the one div compared to another will always be the same when scaled?

Tags: javascript, html, css, grouping

[image]

I have an image of a graph and a dot that has been placed on it by hard-coding the pixels. I'm trying to find if there is a way to add the pixels for the dot in such a way that it'll always remain on the same spot with respective to the image.

This is done in Visual studio in ASP Dot Net Core Entity Framework app using HTML/CSS/Javascript

cshtml page code

[image]

cshtml.cs code

[image: cshtml.cs code]

Comment: Instead of positioning the dot with `px`, as long as its nearest positioned parent is that graph image, use `%` instead.

Comment: A better alternative would be to display the image in a canvas element and then draw the dot on the image using x,y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to wrap the `<img ... />` and `<div class="dot" ... />` in a `<div>` as you already have done. Then apply simple styles.
You just messed up the stylings, I reccomend to read the docs to see how this works rather that ^c ^v.

1. Remove `position:relative;` on the img tag.
2. Change the dot div css to `bottom: 50%`, `top: 50%` and `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` (Search 'center div position absolute')

For more information:

- Transform: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform
- Inset ( top, bottom, right, left generalization ) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset